# EntityProcessingSystem cannot be used with Type Arguments

Tags: c#, generic-type-argument, entity-system, artemis

I am using Artemis and trying to extend `EntityProcessingSystem<SpatialForm, Transform>`.  However, it is telling me `The non-generic type 'Artemis.System.EntityProcessingSystem' cannot be used with type arguments`; however, it must be used with type arguments.  Any idea what is going on here?

I am using Artemis - https://github.com/thelinuxlich/artemis_CSharp
and StarWarrior as my tutorial - https://github.com/thelinuxlich/starwarrior_CSharp

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the question, but for others having the same issue.

see: [Github Forum][1]

Problem with

```
public class RenderSystem : EntityProcessingSystem<SpatialFormComponent, TransformComponent>
```

At least it got my project to build past that point.

Comment: Was there supposed to be a link here?  I also cannot use type arguments.